# How to Disable Multiple Google Chrome Processes

Tags: google-chrome, process, jmeter

I am using JMeter script to call Chrome Driver & open Multiple Chrome Browsers.

Observation : On opening a single Chrome Browser with one tab it is observed that 4 to 5 child processes opened in Task Manager.

I am trying to open 35 Chrome browsers which results ~200+ chrome child processes.

I am using high configured AWS servers with instance type c5.4xlarge but due the above 200+ chrome child processes too much memory is getting consumed. Which results to fail the test after 5 to 6 Hours.

Please let me know if there is any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to use Chrome browser.

As per [WebDriver Sampler Tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the [HTTP Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So the options are in

1. Reconsider using WebDriver as given c5.4xlarge with 16 CPU and 32 GB of RAM you should be able to mimic at least several thousands of virtual users using HTTP protocol level tests. Existing Selenium tests can be converted into JMeter relatively quickly and easily either via [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [Proxy2JMX module of the Taurus tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter/)
2. If you have to stay with browser-based tests you will need at least one more machine of the same specifications in order to run JMeter tests in [Distributed Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) so one machine would start 18 browser instances and another one another 18.